# Force relink when building in QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, linker, static-libraries, qt-creator

I have a subdirs project which wraps a couple libraries and a main application. When I change something in one of the libraries the main application does not relink with them.. does anyone have a trick for getting an application to relink with its statically linked libs automatically when using QtCreator?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a workaround for this and also an interesting discussion on the subject (qmake seems to be the problem here) on the Qt Creator mailing list.

The workaround is to add a `PRE_TARGETDEPS` command to your main applications .pro file, e.g.:

```
PRE_TARGETDEPS += /path/to/your/lib.a
```

This forces the relink.

Comment: Thanks a ton, had found some discussions on the mailing list but had not stumbled across the workaround.

Comment: And the discussion is at... ?:)

Comment: This is obviously not portable to Windows though.

Comment: This is portable on windows, you just need to specify a path and name of the lib.