# Is mingw32-make `-j` option broken?

Tags: android, c++, mingw, qt-creator

I'm compiling a big project (~40 libraries and 1 executable) using QtCreator /w Qt 5.6 for Android. QtCreator uses "mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" to operate the build.

When I compile with default options, all my project compiles fine.

When I add `-j4` or `-j8` to `mingw32-make.exe` command within QtCreator project settings, the build is faster but randomly fails. At some point, while library `B` links with `A`, I can see in the log that it tries to link `B` while `A` compilation is not completed yet, so it reports `cannot open ..../libA.so`.

Note that:

- the fact that `B` links with `A` is managed by `LIBS += -l$$OUT_PWD/../../lib/A/libA.so` in `B`'s .pro file
- `B` appears after `A` in top level .pro file (`SUBDIRS += A.pro B.pro`)

Comment: Make is, unfortunately, not good at handling dependencies when doing a parallel build. That means it could try to build something that depends on something else that is not built yet.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: But QtCreator is the one invoking Make, shouldn't it support that?

Comment: Since QtCreator doesn't set the flag by default, then it's possible that the makefiles created by QtCreator are not set up to handle parallel builds nicely.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Actually it's supported, you just need to specify the build dependencies manually, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Qmake project dependencies (linked libraries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288292/qmake-project-dependencies-linked-libraries), dependecies has to be specified explictely in the .pro files.

So I added in my top level .pro file (after `SUBDIRS += A.pro B.pro`):

```
CONFIG += ordered
B.depends += A
```

Ans also `PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../../lib/A/libA.so` in `B.so`

With those changes, the build with `-j4` option apparently works, and it divided my project compilation time by 3!!